# How do I add an script to all actions of a controller?

Tags: cakephp

I have an script file called 'game.js' which I want to add to all actions inside game_controller.php. 
I think there is a better solution than copy and paste "Html->script('game', array('inline' => false)); ?>" inside all my ctp files. How do I do that?

Comment: I think this link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425084/adding-page-specific-javascript-to-each-view-in-cakephp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you create a sperate layout for given pages and put the script in the layout.  If you simply MUST do this, then you can use the beforeRender() method like so:

[cakephp: can I set $scripts_for_layout from within a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333084/cakephp-can-i-set-scripts-for-layout-from-within-a-controller)